# Appending items to a JSON Array in Scrapy?

Tags: python, arrays, json, scrapy

I am using the python framework Scrapy for scraping websites and storing the data within a json array. To store the data I use the following command:

```
scrapy crawl dmoz -o items.json -t json
```

Every time I call this command however it creates a new JSON array within the file. Is there a way to simply append to the JSON array that is already existing within the file?

I realise Scrapy offers exports for sending items to a certain file format however I have struggled to get this working as effectively as when I run the above command.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [JSON lines format](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#json-lines)

```
scrapy crawl dmoz -o items.jsonl -t jsonlines
```

so that scrapy should append items as lines of JSON objects

Comment: This works great thanks! But is there anyway I can still use the JSON array that my initial command gives me? Than append to that array?